# Can I use a variable instead of the mp3 resource id to play a sound in android

Tags: android, variables, audio, media-player

I was wondering how I could replace the `mp3name` parameter with a variable that matches the MP3 name in the raw file. I have a number of mp3 files to call at various times but only really want to have one MediaPlayer method. Using a String variable does not seem to work as I get the error that the String variable name does not match a raw file.

Eg This does not work when there is an `audiofile.mp3` in the raw file.

```
String playsound

playsound = audiofile

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.playsound);
```

How do I utilise a variable to get this to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an integer. Refer to the file like this.

```
int song1 = R.raw.testsound;
MediaPlayer testPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song1);
```

But using a URI is more the way to go

Comment: Thanks, will check out the URI way

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a variable name, you should use a URI which points to the raw resource. Check out the [MediaPlayer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) (or google around) for some hints.